# Imap search command to get the most recent message?

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

Is there a command to do this? I can get messages since a certain date, or RECENT or UNSEEN, but I can't find any way to just get the newest message and only the newest message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect, the server gives you an EXISTS, telling you how many messages you have.  Take that number (say, 62), and fetch that message: `tag FETCH 62 (whatever)`.  That's the most recent message that's been added to the mailbox.